# is there a proper way to call data using fetch without interruptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, setstate

hello in my application i'm calling about 15-17 apis at my componentWillMount and i'm facing setstate issue, that data does not set in the array and on front end i can see my table blank on front-end
like sometime it sets and sometimes it doesn't
thanks in advance

```js
fetch("campaignNew/backCampaignDetails",{
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
              }).then(res => res.json())
              .then(campaignDetails=>{ 
                  this.setState({BasicDetailArray:campaignDetails,campID:campaignDetails[0].campID,geoLeadChk:campaignDetails[0].requiredCountryWiseAllocation}) 
            }
              )
            fetch("campaignNew/deliveryOptionIncompleteCampaignDetails",{
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
              }).then(res => res.json())
              .then(campaignDetails=>{
                this.setState({DeliveryOption:campaignDetails,marketingChannel:campaignDetails[0].marketingChannel},function(){console.log(this.state.DeliveryOption);this.handleStepTwo()})
              }
              )
              fetch("campaignNew/pacingDetailsForEdit",{
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
              }).then(res => res.json())
              .then(campaignDetail=>{
          if(campaignDetail==""){
            this.pacingMonthlyCalculation()
          }
          else{
            this.setState({PacingDetails: campaignDetail,PacingDetailsBack:campaignDetail})
          }
            })
              fetch("campaignNew/campaignSpecificationDetails",{
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
              }).then(res => res.json())
              .then(campaignDetails=>{
                this.setState({campaignSpecificationDetails:campaignDetails,current:3,display1:'none',display2:'none',display3:'none',display4:'block',geoLeadChk:campaignDetails[0].requiredCountryWiseAllocation})
            }
              )
```

and there's no support from backend

Comment: Could you add a (small) example of what you currently have?

Comment: hello@FunkeyFlo i have added the just a small part of my code

Comment: Try to switch from componentwillmount to componentdidmount https://dev.to/torianne02/componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount-5f0n (componentwillmount is deprecated by the way)

Comment: @NotTheBestAnswer can you explain me how and why

Comment: just a side note, react doesn't wait for your  ajax to end. Check your error. i suggest use promise.all to concurrently get the result, which will fail fast or success.

Comment: @AnonyMouze you mean async fetch() await response.json() correct??

Comment: @RaunakThakkar when you create fetch instance it return promise. You can save all of them in array and use promise.all ,all of them will run concurrently if one fail all fail . You set state so many times ,so react will keep re-rendering alot . Also catch your promise to check error. i think it is blank due to some error that did not get caught,

Comment: @RaunakThakkar `componentwillmount` is deprecated and never was the place to do fetch calls. You just need to replace `componentWillmount` by  `componentDidMount` or insert your fetch inside existing `componentDidMount`. Add a loader for your first render if necessary

Comment: And @AnonyMouze Promise.all is a good advice too. `const promiseA = fetch({...}).then(res => res.json()); ...` then `const [resultA, resultB, ...] = await Promise.all(promiseA, promiseB, ...);` then an unique setState

Comment: @AnonyMouze  thank you so much

Comment: @NotTheBestAnswer thank you so much